# Dúvida com tratamento lógico de duas Strings

Tags: java

Estou com um problema básico de java, andei pesquisando sobre tratamento lógico de strings dentro de uma condição IF, mas não achei a resposta para o meu problema:

```
if (!"y".equals(resposta) || !"n".equals(resposta)) {
    System.out.println("REPOSTA INVÁLIDA!");
    return;
}
```

O programa pediu para o usuário escrever se ele deseja continuar, (yes - y ou no - n), assim se a resposta for DIFERENTE de "y" ou "n", ele irá dar o aviso dentro do bloco if, mas a condição não esta funcionando para a string "n", apenas para a string "y".

Comment: Supondo que o usuário pressione `n` então ele faz a comparação `!"y".equals(resposta)` que será `true` como o operador `||` é curto circuito para verdade o JVM abandona os testes no primeiro `true` pois  se continuasse faria a comparação `!"n".equals(resposta)` que será `false` e finalizaria com `true || false` que é `true` dada a [tabela verdade da disjunção](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela-verdade#Disjun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_(v)). Como quer testar se atende as duas condições use uma conjunção `if (!"y".equals(resposta) && !"n".equals(resposta))`.

Comment: Ah sim, eu fiquei um tempo sem programar e esqueci da diferença do "or" e "and", valeu pela resposta ;D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do ponto de vista lógico você quer capturar todas as respostas que não sejam iguais a `y` ou iguais a `n`.

```
if (!("y".equals(resposta) || "n".equals(resposta))) {
    System.out.println("REPOSTA INVÁLIDA!");
    return;
}
```

A diferença é sutil, a negação se aplica a disjunção como um todo e não a cada condição individual. Ou seja você quer `NÃO(x OU y)`,  o que é logicamente diferente de `NÃO x ou NÃO y`.

Pelas [leis de De Morgan](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teoremas_de_De_Morgan) você também pode reescrever essa  condição de maneira simplificada como:

```
if (!"y".equals(resposta) && !"n".equals(resposta))) {
    System.out.println("REPOSTA INVÁLIDA!");
    return;
}
```

Ou seja, você quer todas as respostas que não sejam `y` **e** também não sejam `n`; i.e., `NÃO y E NÃO n`. Veja [comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/488522/d%c3%bavida-com-tratamento-l%c3%b3gico-de-duas-strings#comment909990_488522) do [Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) para mais detalhes sobre essa solução.